# Variable is always zero

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to assign a variable to a cell value but I'm always getting zero for some reason.

```
Sheets(3).Activate

RowNo = 30
ColNo = 2

EU1 = Range(Cells(RowNo, ColNo).Address()).Value

MsgBox EU1
```

[Check the image for cell address and value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5vpI.png)

The reason why I'm using `Range(Cells(RowNo, ColNo))` is because I have a table that I need to loop into to check the date, if it equals toady (or less than today) the variable EU1 will be updated.

Comment: You could just use `EU1 = Cells(RowNo, ColNo).Value`. `Sheets(3)` may not be the sheet you think it is?

Comment: Qualify your call to `Range` with a worksheet reference.  See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Definitely do not use `.Activate` or `.Select` those are actions of users, not code. Just reference the sheet you want for the range/cell `EU=Sheets(3).Cells(RowNo, ColNo).Value` That's very specific then and you don't have to guess when you look at this line at which worksheet it's referring.

Comment: Does `ActiveSheet.Name` yield the sheet name you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

## Return Value

### A Few Tips

- If you have values that will not change, use constants (`Const`).
- Declare other variables with `Dim`.
- At the beginning of each module, always use `Option Explicit` so VBA will alert you if variables aren't declared (`Dim`, or `Const` ... for
  now).
- For objects (Worksheets, workbooks, ranges) you have to use the
  `Set` statement.

### The Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReturnValue()

    Const cSheet As String = "Sheet3"
    Const cRow As Long = 30
    Const cCol As Long = 2

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim EU1 As Double

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)

    EU1 = ws.Cells(cRow, cCol).Value

    MsgBox EU1

End Sub
```